# Random generated squared floor

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm making a random generated floor, but when a movieclip walks on it , it seems to behave like just a huge block of floor , the MovieClip walks above it, instead of following the image,here's the code:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

//variables

var h:Number = 360;
var floor:MovieClip=new MovieClip;
var guy:MovieClip=new MovieClip;
var gravity=10;

guy.graphics.beginFill(000000);
guy.graphics.drawRect(100,100,15,25);
guy.graphics.endFill();
addChild(guy);//guy creation


//floor generation
for (var i:int=0; i<600; i++)
{

    if (h==360)
    {
        if (Math.random() <= 0.75)
        {
            floor.graphics.beginFill(000000);
            floor.graphics.drawRect(i,h,40,40);
            floor.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(floor);
            i +=  39;
        }
        else
        {
            i +=  39;
        }
        if (i>550)
        {
            h = 320;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    if (h==320)
    {
        if (Math.random() <= 0.75)
        {
            floor.graphics.beginFill(000000);
            floor.graphics.drawRect(i,h,40,40);
            floor.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(floor);
            i +=  39;
        }
        else
        {
            i +=  39;
        }
    }
}


//listeners doesnt matter
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,misc);
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,checkup);
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,checkdown);


//functions

var leftarrow:Boolean=false;
var rightarrow:Boolean=false;

function checkdown(a:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(a.keyCode==37)leftarrow=true;
    if(a.keyCode==39)rightarrow=true;
}

function checkup(a:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(a.keyCode==37)leftarrow=false;
    if(a.keyCode==39)rightarrow=false;
}

function misc(a:Event)
{
    guy.y+=gravity;

    if(guy.hitTestObject(floor))
    {
        gravity=0;
    }else{gravity=10;}

    if(leftarrow)guy.x-=5;
    if(rightarrow)guy.x+=5;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `hitTestObject` evaluates the [bounding boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle) of two `DisplayObject` instances. Your character glides across the holes and pits in your floor because the bounding box encapsulates those holes and pits.

Detecting collisions on a concave shape is difficult. You might have an easier time constructing your floor out of several convex shapes (instead of a single concave shape) and using `hitTestObject` on each of them.

```
var blocks:Array = [ ];

for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Add a convex floor block to blocks.
}

...

gravity = 10

for each (var block:DisplayObject in blocks)
{
    if (guy.hitTestObject(block))
    {
        gravity = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , but you know how to make a convex floor?you saying that I have to do one block by one?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest that (for such a simple game) you build the floor out of individual blocks. You can test the character against each of the blocks on the screen.